# Selenium XHR ERROR: Response_Code = -1

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, xmlhttprequest

I am using the newest version of Selenium RC and firefox 3.5  When I run my test from eclipse I get this error XHR ERROR: Response_Code = -1 Error_Message = Request Error. 
Firefox and Selenium RC open up fine, it seems to try to connect to the remote site I want, but then firefox crashes, any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, the error messages by selenium are in most cases not very useful. I suggest that you start different by first trying to get an example project running. Also, make sure to check the log files generated so that you get an idea when the whole thing crashes.

With such little information, I don't think your question can be answered at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is an issue fixed in trunk (and will come out in the pending 1.0.4 release).  If you download 2.0a5, this includes a 1.0.x compatible Selenium server.  You should be able to drop the -standalone JAR in place and have it work.  If not, building from trunk is your next best bet.

Alternatively, you could try to modify the open command call.  In dynamic languages, such as Ruby, this is fairly straightforward.  open() takes a URL and a boolean as its values.  You'll want to invert the logic for the second param (I think it's false by default, so you'll want true).